# iOS framerate - always 30fps with UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

i want to create a frame-by-frame animation with an array of images.

There is to set the `animationDuration`, the standard value is 1.

Can i be sure that it is always 30fps on every iOS-device when i start the animation with `startAnimating`?

So i need exactly 15 images for a 1 second animation - is there a special calculation i can use when i have more or less than 15 images that have to be animated in exactly one second?

E.g. 60/15*(count number of images in array)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can count on `UIImageView` `animationImages` to give you 30FPS everywhere and everytime.

Indeed, this is meant for very simple and "opportunistic" animations. If you google for it, you will find [reports](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/13966-frame-by-frame-animation-uiimageview-vs-opengl.html) of that method hogging a device (in specific conditions). On the other hand, if your images are small, then chances are that it could work, but you get no guarantees (nor ways to enforce the FPS you need).

> So i need exactly 15 images for a 1 second animation - is there a special calculation i can use when i have more or less than 15 images that have to be animated in exactly one second?

If I understand your question right, then you can try with:

```
duration = number_of_images / FPS; // e.g., 60 images / 30 FPS = 2 seconds
```

of course, if the device will then show properly the 60 images at 30 FPS is another story.

Comment: **Disclaimer: I can't find a reference for this** I believe that it will skip images if it falls behind, similar to what Core Animation does when skipping values, to do its best to take the specified duration. I didn't find any mention of this thought.

Comment: is the 30fps the standard for the animations by using animationImages?

I mean, how can i be sure to use 15 images for a 1 second animation and not 20,30 or 60...

Is there any possibility to read out the actual fps then?

Comment: if you have 15 images and you animate through them using animationImages and specifying 1sec animationDuration, then you will have 15fps. if you specify 0.5sec as animationDuration or your give 30 images, then you will have 30fps. hope this helps.